# cmake cannot find glib2

Tags: macos, cmake, macports

On OS X 10.8.2, I have macports and have installed:

```
glib2
pkg-config
```

among other things. The cmake I run tries to use pkg-config to find glib2. Running `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0`:

`-L/opt/local/lib -lglib-2.0 -lintl`

and `--cflags`:

`-I/opt/local/include/glib-2.0 -I/opt/local/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/opt/local/include`

Yet, when I try to enter these in (individually, or all of them using `;` or `:`), and all sorts of combinations, or when I tried downloading gtk and using the glib2 dirs of that: cmake complains it can't find the directories:

```
checking for module 'gstreamer-0.10'
  found gstreamer-0.10, version 0.10.36
checking for module 'glib-2.0'
  found glib-2.0, version 2.34.3
CMake Error at /Applications/CMake 2.8-10.app/Contents/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:97 (message):
  Could NOT find GLib2 (missing: GLIB2_LIBDIR GLIB2_INCLUDE_DIRS)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /Applications/CMake 2.8-10.app/Contents/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:291 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/Modules/FindGLib2.cmake:127 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  cmake/Modules/FindGStreamer.cmake:12 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:32 (find_package)
```

I saw [this page](http://mac-os-forge.2317878.n4.nabble.com/Package-glib-2-0-not-found-in-pkg-config-search-path-td195399.html) about conflicting `pkg-config`'s with MonoDevelop. I uninstalled Mono, don't have any other pkg-config binaries that I can find, and cleared the cmake cache without any luck. I've looked at the cmake specifics, and its looking for glib.h and glibconfig.h, which are in those directories. Why can't it just behave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this file: http://svn.opensync.org/branches/3rd-party-cmake-modules/modules/FindGLIB2.cmake

In your main CMakeLists.txt file, enter the following line:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/helper/")
```

This is assuming that the above FindGLIB2.cmake is stored in directory /helper off the src.

The contents of this file will help CMake to better find GLIB2.

This link will help you understand how these files work: http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries#Writing_find_modules

Comment: That seems to have worked, thanks. After fixing a few others I have makefiles generated. Of course I overwrote the previous FindGlib2.cmake so I can't diff them and see what the problem was. Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this problem while building `wireshark-3.4.2` from source using `cmake` on `Centos8.2/RHEL8.2`.    The error was

- `Could NOT find GLIB2 (missing: GLIB2_LIBRARY GLIB2_MAIN_INCLUDE_DIR GLIB2_INTERNAL_INCLUDE_DIR) Required is at least version "2.32.0")`

while my system had preinstalled `glib-2.56.4`
Solution: Installed `glib2-devel` package. Then cmake found the glib-2.0 properly.
The cmake output looked like:

- `-- Checking for one of the modules 'glib-2.0'`
- `-- Found GLIB2: /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so (found suitable version "2.56.4", minimum required is "2.32.0")`